# dplyr mutate getting stuck for seemingly straightforward mutation

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I am trying to add some columns to my dataframe using `dplyr`. The mutations seem straightforward to me, but the code does not seem to be running as expected (not completing within 12+ hours). I can't help but feel I'm missing something...

```
 wcdata <- wcdata %>%
   group_by(betId) %>% 
   mutate(markets=n_distinct(MarketCode),
          states=n_distinct(State1),
          legs=n(),
          eventTypes=n_distinct(eventType)) %>%
   ungroup()
```

For some context,

- the `wcdata` dataframe is about 13 million x 20
- There are about 5 million unique `betId`
- `MarketCode` is a factor of about 100 possible levels will have `n_distinct` of at most 10 for each unique `betId` (usually less)
- `State1` is a factor of 2 possible levels
- `eventType` is a factor of 2 possible levels
- Each `betId` will have between 1 and 20 `legs`, the average being around 3.

Am I doing something wrong or is there another way to do what I want (I think it's fairly obvious from the code snippet what I'm trying to achieve - correct me if I'm wrong)?

Comment: Code looks correct and as one can guess that creating over 13 million different lists (`n_distinct` calls) will take time. I'm just wondering why do you want to use `mutate` and add such values with every column? Why not `summarise`?

Comment: @MKR basically because I need to keep all the other columns, although I guess I could use `summarise` and then `join`...maybe thats inefficient but oh well!

Comment: If you have so many records, you might want to check if data.table is not faster.

Comment: @phiver 's advice is sound; however, if you want to stay in the tidyverse, you should check out the `multidplyr` package, which implements parallel processing. Here is a link for you: http://blog.aicry.com/multidplyr-dplyr-meets-parallel-processing/index.html